# Using CMD to compile Jar files (for class use) with Java Files

Tags: java, class, object, jar, gson

I am trying to use the Gson Java library for ArrayLists to JSON object class use.

My current Bat code for compiling it is this:

```
      @echo off
      javac -cp ".;/gson-2.8.2.jar" AdobeExtender.java
      java -cp ".;/gson-2.8.2.jar" AdobeExtender
      pause
```

This is what I am using in my java code to call the class in the jar file

```
    String aeKeysJson = new Gson().toJson(aeKeys);
```

I am using the gson-2.8.2.jar. These are all in the same directory.
The file will not compile and will not recognize the class gson.

Comment: What is the error message? What does your `import` statement for the `Gson` class look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the slash character `/` before the name of the gson-2.8.2.jar, in this way

```
@echo off
javac -cp ".;gson-2.8.2.jar" AdobeExtender.java
java -cp ".;gson-2.8.2.jar" AdobeExtender
pause
```

Comment: It seems there is a problem for the compiler recognizing the Gson class maybe you are missing the `import com.google.gson.Gson;` or you could use the fully qualified name `String aeKeysJson = new com.google.gson.Gson().toJson(aeKeys);`, this is example that I used to answer the question you can download to checked with you example https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dCDkEWNFlvGiKM9r_Jf3IoaXZ8wLiSTx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: *Blows brains out with imaginary gun* 

I didn't notice or realize we have to write that import statement. I thought that was only for IDE's.